# Custom key for multiple cursor in VSCode

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

In VS Code you need to use <kbd>alt</kbd> to set multiple cursors. Is there any way to change it to, maybe, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>? Using <kbd>alt</kbd> really annoys me as it's less comfortable to me and it always toggles menu bar which I hid on Windows:

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wJkn.png)

Or maybe is there any other solution, maybe to change key that toggles menu? I couldn't find any useful shortcut entries in shortcuts config of vs code.

Comment: There's a config file with key bindings in it.  I don't know where it is or what it's named, but I know it exists.  Go forth and search!

Comment: @Will, As I said in the question, I checked it and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Will do you even read what I say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to customize mouse shortcuts, the feature request for that is here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3130

It's actually completely unusable on most Linux distributions as it's an OS-level shortcut.